# I have some doubts regarding how to implement child theme

Tags: themes, child-theme

In https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes they have given 2 different enqueue codes, what's the difference between them?

This is the first one

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

This is the second one

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Whats the difference between the two and which one should be used and would this code work across all the wordpress themes ?

Second doubt I have is about a rtl.css file. I have this file name rtl.css in my theme. 
Do I need to enqueue rtl.css too using

```
 wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
```

After adding rtl.css in the child theme directory

```
To support RTL languages, add rtl.css file to your child theme, containing:

/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen Child
Template: twentyfourteen
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function should be there in your parent theme functions.php file.

**Parent Theme Code**

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
        function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
}
?>
```

**Child Theme Code**

Now place the following code in your child theme. Setting 'parent-style' as a dependency will ensure that the child theme stylesheet loads after it.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_parent_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_child_style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array('my_parent_style')
        );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
    }
}
```

Hope it's clear.

**2nd Doubt**
It's recommended to add the `rtl.css` file to your child theme even if the parent theme has no `rtl.css` file. `rtl.css` is only loaded by WordPress if [is_rtl()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_rtl) returns true.

Comment: I read some tutorials online it doesnt say you have to add the code in the function.php of parent theme but only child theme. Will it not work if i dont add the first code inside the functions.php of the parent theme.

Comment: It works without adding the first code in the parent theme but it's the correct way to enqueue the style in the parent theme.